# Wrong Visualitation in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm tring to wrinte an java application that disposes in a gridBagLayout one jlabel and one JtextFiel. I don't understand why my first jLabel is not aligned with the other. This is my code:

```
public class FinestraSceltaIntervalli extends JFrame {

    private final String stringa="Modifica Parametri";
    private int numeroIntervalli;


    private JScrollPane scrollPanel;
    private SingletonFinestra singleton;
    private JButton conferma;
    private JButton pulisci;
    private JButton indietro;
    private JTextField campo;
    private JLabel label;
    public FinestraSceltaIntervalli(int numeroIntervalli){
        this.numeroIntervalli=numeroIntervalli;
        singleton=SingletonFinestra.getSingleton();
        conferma=new JButton("dfsd");
        pulisci=new JButton("Pulisci");
        campo=new JTextField();
        setSize(singleton.getFinestra().getWidth(),singleton.getFinestra().getHeight());
        setLocation((int)singleton.getFinestra().getLocation().getX(),(int)singleton.getFinestra().getLocation().getY());
        setTitle(stringa);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel container=new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout layout=new GridBagLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<numeroIntervalli;i++){
            label=new JLabel("ciao");

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=i;
        c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            layout.setConstraints(label, c);
            container.add(label);
            campo=new JTextField();
            c.gridx=1;
            c.insets.right=0;
            c.ipadx=100;
            c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            layout.setConstraints(campo, c);
            container.add(campo);

        }

    scrollPanel=new JScrollPane(container);
    add(scrollPanel);

}
}
```

This is the output:

[image: http://it.tinypic.com/r/345dco4/8]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Totally Gridbag https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuLaxbFKAcc "ok, that looks like ... shit"

Answer (score 2):

Just make one change.

Set `c.ipadx = 0;` before adding `JLabel` in the `container` or remove `c.ipadx = 100;`.

Since `c.ipadx = 100;` is used for other `JLabel`s except first one in loop that's why first `JLabel` is positioned different from other `JPanel`s.

Just have a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and learn more about [GridBagConstraints#ipadx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#ipadx)